# Java 7 WatchService -- ENTRY_MODIFY triggered on file open

Tags: java, watchservice

I have a program that watches a directory for file update using `WatchService`.
I get events when I modify a file. However, I notice that even if I open a file in vi, and do not modify its contents, the watch service `poll` method is invoked.
My code is as follows:

```
watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
Path path = Paths.get("conf");
path.register(watcher, ENTRY_MODIFY);
WatchKey key = null;

key = watcher.poll(MAX_WAIT_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
if (key != null) {
for (WatchEvent<?> events : key.pollEvents()) {
        WatchEvent<Path> ev = cast(events);
        Path fileName = ev.context();
    }
```

In the above code, watcher.poll waits for `MAX_WAIT_TIME` for an `ENTRY_MODIFY` event. However, when I open a file within the directory being watched, and close without changing its contents... the `watcher.poll` receives an event and stops waiting.
Is there some parameter that needs to be set and I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you save the file before closing, the OS will see the file as modified even if there is no change to it and these will trigger the ENTRY_MODIFY event.
Also your code is taking only one watch key. If you want continue watching the directory you need to put your watcher.poll instruction into a loop.

Comment: I am running my program on unix. I open a file in vi and close it without saving. As soon as I exit the file, I see the watcher.poll exit from the waiting mode.
What I have posted above is a snippet of the actual code, the watcher.poll instruction is running in a loop and handling all genuine modify events correctly. Only issue is that it gets an event even if a file is plainly opened in vi and closed without modification.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the below code in java7 and it works fine for me in windows.Also please try the watchkey reset option.Below is the code used for WatchService:

```
                    import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
                    import java.nio.file.Path;
                    import java.nio.file.Paths;
                    import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
                    import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
                    import java.nio.file.WatchService;
                    import java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds;

                    public class WatchServiceJava7Feature {


                        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                            System.out.println("here ");
                            WatchService  watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
                            Path path= Paths.get("C:\\User\\code\\watchservice\\");
                            System.out.println("here 1");
                            path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE,StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE,StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);
                            while(true)
                            {
                            WatchKey key = watchService.take(); // this will return the keys
                            for(WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) 
                             {
                                 WatchEvent<Path> watchEvent = (WatchEvent<Path>) event;
                                 WatchEvent.Kind<Path> kind = watchEvent.kind();
                                 switch(kind.name()) {
                                    case "ENTRY_MODIFY":
                                        System.out.println("Case Modify :Event on "+ event.context().toString() + " is "+ kind);
                                        break;
                                    case "ENTRY_DELETE":
                                        System.out.println("Case Delete :Event on "+ event.context().toString() + " is "+ kind);
                                        break; 
                                    case "ENTRY_CREATE":
                                        System.out.println("Case Create :Event on "+ event.context().toString() + " is "+ kind);
                                        break; 
                                }         

                             }
                             key.reset();  
                           }

                        }

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very well documented, but changes to a file's metadata such as last accessed time will trigger a `ENTRY_MODIFY` event. My guess is your operating system and file system are changing the last accessed time when the editor opens the file. This would cause the watch service to return with `ENTRY_MODIFY` even though the editor doesn't change the contents of the file.

The OS and FS behavior can vary widely. For example, some file systems like NTFS have access times disabled by default. Other filesystems like EXT4 can have them disabled as an option (mounting with -noatime). This is done for performance reasons, especially historically with HDDs because modifying metadata would incur an expensive disk seek. For Windows/NTFS, even if accessed times are enabled, there's a separate registry setting that determines the delay with atimes are updated, which I assume is also for performance reasons - it's faster to update atime once every hour instead of every time the file is actually accessed.

To get more watch events, you need to do both of the following:

- **wrap your polling and events loop** in a `while (true)` loop or similar to keep re-polling for new changes
- after handling the `WatchEvent`s, **call `key.reset()`**

If you don't call `key.reset()`, then the `poll` (and related methods like `take`) will not return with that key again. Not sure why Java has this behavior, maybe it's a way to "unsubscribe" from watch events of that type.

So here are the minimal changes:

```
while (true) { // FIRST CHANGE: keep polling for more events
    key = watcher.poll(MAX_WAIT_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if (key != null) {
        for (WatchEvent<?> events : key.pollEvents()) {
            WatchEvent<Path> ev = cast(events);
            Path fileName = ev.context();
        }
        key.reset() // SECOND CHANGE: reset key so service will return it again
    }
}
```

To avoid the `poll` from blocking the rest of your code, you can create a `Thread`, put the entire `while (true) ...` inside the thread's `run()` method, then call `thread.start()`.